# Android Gradle ~ How to add Maven to get Android spring security?

Tags: android, spring, maven, spring-mvc, gradle

I'm using Android Studio 1.3

I started a project and created some activities. I need to Auth on my WebApi with Spring Security CSRF Token so I did some research and the spring docs say to use spring-android-auth-{version}.jar, spring-android-rest-template-{version}.jar and a few others.

My project actually uses Gradle, how do I transfer it to Maven to get the dependencies like in the Maven pom.xml ? I Need Json dependencies too, to convert my java objects to JSON strings and send via POST to my API.

Is it the best practice to use Spring Security Csrf Token for the API security, and authenticate my mobile device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask a few questions here, I'll take a shot at **how to add a Maven project as a Gradle dependency**.

Go to your module level `build.gradle` file in your app. Add the following lines underneath

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application`

```
repositores {
  mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://your-maven-repository"
    }
}
```